# what will happen when a thread T1 joins thread T2 and T2 gets interupted

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a scenario where thread T1 joins thread T2. what will happen when thread T2 gets interrupted. whether T1 will proceed or T1  will also gets interrupted.

Comment: hi,why don't you try running it yourself...? what happens when you do?

Comment: interrupt it is a flag only and from sleep a weak up, it will be like t2 finished execution normally. But you can test this in 5 line of code..

Answer (score 2):

If thread joins another thread, it waits till the thread `die` (according to spec). So no matter what happened, if second thread stops, the waiting thread will continue running.

> public final void join()
>                   throws InterruptedException
>
> Waits for this thread to die.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing will necessarily happen to thread T1, because `join()` is waiting on he thread to *die*, which has nothing to do with it being *interrupted*.

"Interrupted" does not mean "killed", which is what `join()` is waiting for. It's up to the code running in the thread as to what happens when the thread is interrupted. For example, a thread can chose to catch `InterruptedException`, ignore it and keep running.